# How to pick a directory in android

Tags: android, xamarin, android-intent, android-activity, directory

I am opening the folder picker with this:

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ActionOpenDocumentTree);
intent2.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
intent2.PutExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true);
intent2.PutExtra("android.content.extra.FANCY", true);
intent2.PutExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_FILESIZE", true);
_this.StartActivityForResult(intent2, SELECT_FOLDER_REQUEST);
```

The callback I'm using is this:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == SELECT_FOLDER_REQUEST)
    {
        if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
        {
            Debugger.Log(0, "cat", "The path is: " + data.DataString + "\r\n");
        }
    }
}
```

The folder picker does appear, but as soon as it does. The `OnActivityResult` function is called with the `resultCode` being `Canceled` and the `data` parameter being `null`.

Then when I do click the "select" button in the picker. The folder picker closes and `OnActivityResult` does not get called with selected folder in the `data` parameter.

How can I select a folder in Android?

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work by dropping the `ActivityFlags.NewTask` flag.